Error using npm create vite@latest: "require() of ES modules is not supported"
I'm trying to set up a new Vite project using the command:
npm create vite@latest
After confirming to proceed with the installation of create-vite@5.5.1, I get the following error:
(node:58326) Warning: require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/username/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/username/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/package.json.
/Users/username/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/index.js:3
import './dist/index.mjs'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11
npm error code 1
npm error path /Users/username
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c create-vite
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2024-08-14T02_51_37_222Z-debug-0.log

Package.json:
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.28",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.4.0"
  }
}

Steps to Reproduce:
Run npm create vite@latest.
Confirm installation when prompted.
Environment:
Node.js version: v22.6.0
npm version: 10.8.2
Operating System: macOS Sonoma
What I've Tried:

Uninstalled and reinstalled all Node.js-related tools to ensure they were up-to-date.
Ran brew update to ensure Homebrew and its packages were current.
Manually updated the versions in package.json to their latest.
Attempted to revert to CommonJS by removing the "type": "module" field.
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json, then ran npm install.
Ran npm cache clean --force
I renamed the file as suggested, but it didn't resolve the issue.
I tried to modify the code to use dynamic import() statements instead of require(), but i kept getting the error.
I removed the "type": "module" from the package.json in the relevant directories, but this led to other compatibility issues or just flat out did not fix the problem

Question:
How can I resolve this error and successfully create a new Vite project using the latest version? Is there a configuration or workaround needed to avoid these ES module issues? I've attached my package.json of a current vite project that I have downloaded as well to show that doesn't work either.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

But did you try any of the very helpful suggestions in the error message?

@TimRoberts Yes I have! I renamed the file as suggested, but it didn't resolve the issue.
I tried to modify the code to use dynamic import() statements instead of require(), but i kept getting the error.
I removed the "type": "module" from the package.json in the relevant directories, but this led to other compatibility issues or just flat out did not fix the problem.
Despite these attempts, the error still occurs. I'm looking for any other potential fixes or insights that could help resolve this issue.

surprised your package.json does not have "type": "module"

I've tried adding it, ive tried removing it as well. Still the same outcome. Im very confused

so strange, when I npm create vite@latest the package.json includes it, and doesn't have half the cruft you have in yours - e.g. tailwind, framer-motion, react-icons, react-scroll - how did they get in there?

Oh, wait. Is this an error when running npm create vite@latest or when trying to run npm install once the create has completed?

Im including 2 different scenarios if you read through the question. One scenario where I attempt to use npm create vite@latest to create a new project & another scenario where it is a downloaded vite project and running npm run dev

The issue here is that create-vite is trying to use import statements (which are specific to ES modules), but Node.js is attempting to load it using require.
I suggest you install and switch to node version 18.2 using Homebrew as it supports ES modules, and has better compatibility.
Command
->> brew install node@18
You can also try to create a vite project using npx
->> npx create-vite@latest
If you prefer to use nvm, you can also install node 18 using nvm and switch to it. You might find this easier
Commands
->> nvm install 18 //install a specific version of node
->> nvm ls   //list installed versions of node (via nvm)
->> nvm use 18 //Use the latest available node 18 release
->> node -v //check node version

Hi Sofiyullahi, thank you so much for your reply. I have installed node version 18.2 and verified the version (npm -v returns 10.7.0 & node -v returns v18.20.4). However I'm unfortunately still getting the exact same error. Is there anything else I can do?

Did you try to install using npx?

Additionally, if you have previously installed create-vite globally on your Mac, you should uninstall it and try again using npx.
if that does not help, try to do a clean uninstallation of node and re-install just version 18 using nvm.

Yes, I ran brew install node@18 as well as nvm install 18. I verified all installed versions of node. I used nvm use 18 and then used nvm alias default 18. verified this again with nvm ls to ensure it is correctly set. Double checked my node -v and it is v18.20.4. However same issue. I also attempted to use npx as opposed to npm when creating a project with vite - and I am getting the exact same error unfortunately.

I will try the uninstall methods now and get right back to you. Thank you again Sofiyullahi

Just uninstalled all node related tools (npm,nvm) and verified using which npm,npx, node and which nvm. Reinstalled nvm using brew & added necessary source lines to .zshrc. Installed node 18 using the commands provided and verified the version being used and installed is 18. Version being returned in terminal was (node v18.20.4 (npm v10.7.0)). However when running npx create-vite@latest, I continue to get the same error.
